# Xcode 4 not showing line that debugger is stopped on

Tags: debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

When I place a breakpoint on a line in XCode 4, and it stops at that breakpoint, it doesn't show the line that is highlighted initially or when I step.  This only happens once--when I initially open XCode.  It will show the line, and then every run after that it won't.

Any ideas how to bring it back?  It's XCode 4.0.2.  I've read a lot about XCode being broken, and I've experienced that too, but is there anything I can do?

Edit: I've also tried reinstalling XCode from a fresh download.

Comment: send a bug report to Apple and hope it gets fixed at some point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by deleting XCode and reinstalling.  Just updating to the newer version would not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
debug -> debug Workflow -> always show Disassembly (uncheck).
```

This works for me[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfolding All the code and restarting xcode solved my problem.
Irtaza