# Xcode not displaying line number or exception in debugger output

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

For some reason, Xcode is not displaying the line number of the exception, or even the crash itself in the Debugger Output. I have no breakpoints set and it's being built for Debug. The debugger is set to LLDB. I'm not sure how this became onset, but it's badly affecting my workflow now.

[image: How the debugger currently looks.]

This isn't how it was before (would display main.m), but I have no idea how it happened.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your breakpoints.  Up in the top bar, unselect the button labeled `Breakpoints`.

You likely accidentally clicked on a line and enabled a breakpoint.  Additionally, you can click on the button that looks like a play button with a line preceding it to continue the program execution.  It is located on the bar above your console output.

Comment: With the breakpoints now off, the debugger output now shows the exception. However, the main display in the center of the screen is still not displaying the main.m file as it was before. Is this normal?

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]'`

Comment: Now post your code related to the array you're using.  Stating the obvious, you're trying to access an object in an array with an invalid index.  (Protip: update your original question)

Comment: The exception shouldn't be the problem however. It shouldn't be displaying this in the center, rather it should be displaying main.m itself. And if I try to use breakpoints, I can't see them in the implementation, which I do need.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, this question is not about the exception itself, rather why Xcode is displaying this output rather than the normal one I have been seeing.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now.  Interesting, I'm not sure why it'd do that.  Try cleaning you're project, I believe I recall seeing a similar question where that was the solution.  Cmd + Shift + K

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29872/discussion-between-gizmoloon-and-rog)

Comment: Not sure if you're still in our chat, so I'll post these suggestions I found here as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323529/ios-debugging-not-working-in-xcode & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333457/xcode-4-not-showing-line-that-debugger-is-stopped-on .. good luck, @Gizmoloon!

Comment: Nope, sorry, even deleting and redownloading Xcode proved fruitless.